# Choosing between GlusterFS replica 2 or 3

Tags: glusterfs

I can't figure out the relation between the number of bricks and replica count.

I have 4 server nodes and after running the command to create a distributed replicated volume, with a replica count of 2, the following message appears:

> "Replica 2 volumes are prone to split-brain. Use Arbiter or Replica 3
>   to avoid this. See:
>   http://docs.gluster.org/en/latest/Administrator%20Guide/Split%20brain%20and%20ways%20to%20deal%20with%20it/."

The documentation also says

> "The number of bricks should be equal to of the replica count for a
>   replicated volume."

Would it make sense to choose a replica count of 3 in this case? As far as I understand, this would only make sense if I had 6 server nodes - Is it because it makes more sense to say we have a file replicated across 3 replica volumes (considering node1-2, node3-4 and node5-6 are the 3 replica volumes)?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the answer: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_gluster_storage/3.3/html/administration_guide/sect-creating_distributed_replicated_volumes

Comment: What replica count you used for 4 node, I am in same situation, if I use 3 then fourth node will have no brick which mean I can't use 4 node, in case of replica 2 there are chances of split brain(as it will create distributed replica)